# Privoxy as intercepting proxy

Tags: wordpress, privoxy

I want to setup Privoxy to be able to filter all http requests that my Wordpress page are sending and receiving, but I have hard time trying to do it.

I setup Wordpress with bitnami package and privoxy with apt-get install and found out that in order to intercept all of requests I have to turn on "accept-intercepted-requests" and actually redirect them with iptables.
I Tried this command to do so:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8118
```

But when I try to access website outside of localhost I have connection refused message.

My question is: is it possible to intercept all http request of webserver with privoxy and iptables or maybe I have to use some other software to achieve this?

Comment: Your solution is not working because "all http request of webserver" are intercepted/redirected to privoxy, and now privoxy cannot find wordpress which is running on port 80, but iptables is redirecting it to 8118.   Maybe [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) is an easier way, but I do not have enough experience to tell you how to set that up (to get what you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, so I am posting solution for anyone who also struggles with this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i {INTERFACE_NAME} -p tcp --dport {WEBSITE_PORT} -j REDIRECT --to-port {PROXY_PORT}
```

where:

- `INTERFACE_NAME` - name of your VM interface which can be get with the `ifconfig` command (for me it was `ens33`)
- `WEBSITE_PORT` - port on which your apache2 service is listening (default is 80 or 8080)
- `PROXY_PORT` - port of Privoxy (default is 8118)

It works with every website that is hosted using Apache. (I tested it also with phpBB and it works with no problems.)